# how to remove an object from a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am traversing on a list and I want to remove an object based on a condition while traversing so that the object information is not shown under my cshtml page. i.e if my end month value is smaller than the isValidActivityPosition than I dont want to show that element value in the ui:

Below is what I am trying to do:**

**.js**

```
//the "priorityObj.UpcomingActivities" has two objects under it [0] and [1]
if (priorityObj.UpcomingActivities() != "") {
    $.each(priorityObj.UpcomingActivities(), function (i, v) {
        monthPosition = v.ActivityDateToDisplay().split(',')[0].substring(0, 3).trim();           

        var isValidActivityPosition = jQuery.inArray(monthPosition, priorityMonth);
        //if the variable isValidActivityPosition is greater than endMonth
        //than remove the object which is currently traversed upon in the $.each
        if (isValidActivityPosition > endMonth) {
            v.remove();
        }

    });
}
```

**cshtml page**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:UpcomingActivities()">
            <div class="priority-icon">
```

I dont know what should I write in place of **v.remove** so that the current element is removed and should not be shown in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 temp = priorityObj.UpcomingActivities();//create temporar object
if (priorityObj.UpcomingActivities() != "") {
    $.each(priorityObj.UpcomingActivities(), function (i, v) {
        monthPosition = v.ActivityDateToDisplay().split(',')[0].substring(0, 3).trim();           

        var isValidActivityPosition = jQuery.inArray(monthPosition, priorityMonth);
        //if the variable isValidActivityPosition is greater than endMonth
        //than remove the object which is currently traversed upon in the $.each
        if (isValidActivityPosition > endMonth) {
            temp.splice(i,1);//remove data from it
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: ivascuL thank you for your reply. Actually this code will remove the object from the view model as well. I want a temporary solution that will hide the value temporary

Comment: create a temporal object and use it instead

Answer (score 0):

```
//the "priorityObj.UpcomingActivities" has two objects under it [0] and [1]
if (priorityObj.UpcomingActivities() != "") {
    $.each(priorityObj.UpcomingActivities(), function (i, v) {
        monthPosition = v.ActivityDateToDisplay().split(',')[0].substring(0, 3).trim();           

        var isValidActivityPosition = jQuery.inArray(monthPosition, priorityMonth);
        //if the variable isValidActivityPosition is greater than endMonth
        //than remove the object which is currently traversed upon in the $.each
        if (isValidActivityPosition > endMonth) {
            $(this).remove();
        }

    });
}
```